# CorePlot not calling doubleForPlot-method

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I followed a mix of this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2 and my old code with CorePlot 1.4
Now I try to use 2.0 and I can see a graph but no values in it.

The CPTGraphHoldingView is added in the storyboard. Then in code I added a CPTXYGraph and a CPTScatterPlot. The ViewController has added this `<CPTPlotDataSource>`.
The ScatterPlot's dataSource is set to self, the view which is a valid CPTPlotDataSource.

But in the End, when I execute it does everything BUT calling

```
-(double)doubleForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx {
   ...
}
```

and

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {
   ...
}
```

What else might be important?

Comment: The dataSource is usually the viewController, not the view.

Comment: It is in the ViewController. But I got it now. I missed the initialization -.- Had ``CPTScatterPlot *_powerPlot;`` but forgot ``_powerPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];``. There was no warning, no hint. Nothing. I was just dealing with a null-value and nobody told me. Sorry, I'm new to iOS. C# wouldn't allow that o,o